# help with a calculation

Tags: calculus

can someone help me out, how the third equality (marked by two asterisk) arises? The last two terms seem clear, but I don't understand how the sigma sign terms end up being $ a_n -a_1 $ Also I'm not sure where the $ a_{n+1} $ in the second equality (marked by one asterisk) comes from..I'm missing something :-/

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n(a_{k+1}-a_k)= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)*+a_{n+1}*-a_n = **a_n-a_1 +a_{n+1}-a_n** $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: The sum is considered from $1$ to $n-1$ and not from $1$ to $n.$

Comment: Do an example with, say, $n = 4$. It should become clear why this holds.

Comment: ahh..I see :)..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the series 
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)&=a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+...+a_2-a_1+a_1-a_0\\
&=a_n-a_0
\end{align}
$$.

This is called a "telescopic sum" because you have internal cancellations.

See Mathworld article: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html

See wiki for telescoping series(infinite telescoping sum):http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: got it..Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not only is this an example of a "telescoping series," it appears to be the
inductive step in a *proof* of the standard way to sum a telescoping series.

To prove: for any integer $m \geq 1,$ $$\sum_{k=1}^m(a_{k+1}-a_k) = a_{m+1}-a_1.$$

Base case: $m = 1.$ Then the series has only one term:
$$\sum_{k=1}^m(a_{k+1}-a_k) = \sum_{k=1}^1(a_{k+1}-a_k) = a_2-a_1.$$

Inductive step: Assume the formula is true for $m = n - 1.$ Then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{k+1}-a_k) & = & (a_{n+1}-a_n) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k) \\
& = & (a_{n+1}-a_n) + (a_n-a_1) \\
& = & a_{n+1}-a_1
\end{eqnarray}$$
and therefore the formula is true for $m = n.$

The first two lines of that last set of equations is precisely the set
of equations in the question.
We know that the telescoping sum for $n - 1$ is $a_n-a_1$ because that is
precisely what the assumption of the inductive step says.
(And it is in fact true for the same reason that the inductive step assumption
is always true in a successful proof by induction.)